# Javascript arrays to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have three arrays

```
var x ={x1,x2,x3,x4,x1,x2,x4,x3...}
var y ={y1,y1,y1,y1,y2,y3,y4...}
var z ={a,b,c,d,...}
```

There is a 1:1:1 correspondence between all three values. Where x is the row and y is column and z is value.

I want to create a JSON in javascript like

```
{
 x1{
    y1:a,
    y2:f
   },
 x2{
    y1:b,
    y2:h
  },
  x3{...},
   x4{}
}
```

Basically create row JSON x1{} with all the column name and values separated by comma

Comment: _I have three arrays_ - Are they?

Comment: please add some real data and the wanted outcome, and what you have tried to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the `x` array and take the value as key for the object and from `y` the value of the same index as key of the inner object, then assign the value of the same index of `v`.

The result is an object with nested keys and all values.

```js
var x = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x1', 'x2', 'x4', 'x3'],
    y = ['y1', 'y1', 'y1', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y4'],
    v = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    result = {};

x.forEach(function (k, i) {
    result[k] = result[k] || {};
    result[k][y[i]] = v[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```